# Does showing content of other site using .htaccess rewrite function cause security vulnerable?

Tags: .htaccess, security, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Let's suppose I have a app running on heroku with heroku's SSL, and I have a domain that has Let's encrypt DV SSL.

Will it cause security vulnerable if I use .htaccess function rewrite (**NOT REDIRECT**) to show contents on heroku app on my own domain? Since I know if we use iframe or redirect it won't be vulnerable if both connection point has SSL encryption, but how about rewrite?

P.S. The rule I'm using is something like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond #{HTTP_HOST} example.com
RewriteRule (.*) example.herokuapp.com/$1
```

PPS. If anyone knows there is issue or security holes in the htaccess rule welcome to point out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't rewrite to another external website without the apache proxy, and mod_proxy dose have indeed some security issues:

From Apache site:

> The forward proxy is activated using the ProxyRequests directive.
>   Because forward proxys allow clients to access arbitrary sites through
>   your server and to hide their true origin, it is essential that you
>   secure your server so that only authorized clients can access the
>   proxy before activating a forward proxy.

Comment: With your quoted text do you meant if we're sure that both two site has been encrypted with SSL it'll still be safe?

Comment: no that s not what I ment but why do you not use just the domain directly? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Comment: Notice I'm using free plan, and for rewriting is because I already have a normal hosting plan, also why not use heroku subdomains? It's quite personal perfect using own domain makes it looks better

Comment: My Opinion: in your case I would say its "Save enough" but its not a good practice, because you lose a lot of performance if your web server is just a forward proxy.